# If $x(u, v)$ and $y(u, v)$ have continuous derivatives, then $x_{u}(u,v)y_v(x,v) = x_uy_v-x_vy_u$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $x(u, v)$, $y(u, v)$ have continuous derivatives, then
$$x_{u}(u,v)y_v(x,v) = x_uy_v-x_vy_u$$
The RHS is Jacobian determinant. I actually believe this holds for more than two variables. Since the notation here is confusing (I don't mean substitute x for all u in $y_v(x,v)$, but we use x and v to represent u in y's expression. We can do this because x=x(u,v)), let me take one example.

Let $x=u\cos(v), y=u\sin(v)$. In this case, the $\text{RHS}=u$. And for computing the $\text{LHS}$, we first use $x$ and $v$ to replace $u$ in the expression of $y$. So we have $y=\tan(v)x$ and $y_v(x,v)=\frac{x}{\cos^2(v)}$. And $x_u(u,v)$ is simply $\cos(v)$. So when we multiply them together we get
$$\frac{x}{\cos^2(v)}\cos(v)=\frac{x}{\cos(v)}=\frac{u\cos(v)}{\cos(v)}=u$$ Thus $\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}$.

This is found by me when I was trying to change variables without using Jacobian determinant. I just change one variable first, then swap the integral order and change the other variable. And I get the same result as use Jacobian determinant. That's where this formula comes from.

I think maybe we can prove it just using partial derivatives. But I don't know how. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since now I am more familiar with the notations I am now (almost) able to answer this question.
What I am trying to prove here is actually $$x_uy_v(u(x,v),v)=x_uy_v-x_vy_u$$
The chain rule tells us $x_uy_v(u(x,v),v)=x_u(y_uu_v(x,v)+y_v)=x_uy_uu_v(x,v)+x_uy_v$.
Now cancel the $x_uy_v$ from both sides, what we need to prove becomes
$$\begin{split}
&x_uy_uu_v(x,v)=-x_vy_u \\
\Leftrightarrow\ & x_uu_v(x,v)=-x_v\\
\Leftrightarrow\ & x_uu_v(x,v)+x_v=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow\ & x_v(u(x,v),v)=0
\end{split}$$
I am pretty sure $x(u(x,v),v)=x$, so $x_v(u(x,v),v)=0$ ,although I don't know how to state it rigorously.